# How to configure maven install to skip tests by default?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I was wondering if it's possible to configure maven to skip unit tests by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the settings.xml file, inside the `properties` tag, add this property: **maven.test.skip** to true.

```
    <profiles>
         <profile>
              <id>development</id>
              <properties>
                  <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
              </properties>
         </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
         <activeProfile>development</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

If the, you want to execute this tests, you can override the property:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=false
```

Comment: Could you let me know the position of your `properties` tag? Is it in a `profile` as my answer below?

Comment: Yes, the property must be inside a profile as explained in your answer below.

Comment: I hoped that there is another way(your way) to configure :D. Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by adding a `profile` element to the `settings.xml` file:

```
<profile>
    <id>skip.tests.by.default</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score -2):

For Eclipse Photon,

1. Right click on pom.xml
2. Run as 'maven build...' (note the '...')
3. Type 'clean install'
4. Check the 'skip tests' and Run